# Java GUI code with Swing Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have the following questions for the below code:

1. Is there a simpler implementation of an on-screen counter?
2. I made `CountTimer` inner class since it's tightly coupled with the GUI part anyway. What would be the best way to uncouple them?

```
package count_timer;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CountTimerGUI implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    private JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();

    private JButton startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton pauseBtn = new JButton("Pause");
    private JButton resumeBtn = new JButton("Resume");
    private JButton stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
    private JButton resetBtn = new JButton("Reset");

    private JButton greenBtn = new JButton("Green");
    private JButton redBtn = new JButton("Red");

    private CountTimer cntd;


    public CountTimerGUI() {
        setTimerText("         ");
        GUI();
    }

    private void GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        timeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        panel.add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        startBtn.addActionListener(this);
        pauseBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resumeBtn.addActionListener(this);
        stopBtn.addActionListener(this);
        resetBtn.addActionListener(this);
        greenBtn.addActionListener(this);
        redBtn.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel cmdPanel = new JPanel();
        cmdPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        cmdPanel.add(startBtn);
        cmdPanel.add(pauseBtn);
        cmdPanel.add(resumeBtn);
        cmdPanel.add(stopBtn);
        cmdPanel.add(resetBtn);

        panel.add(cmdPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel clrPanel = new JPanel();
        clrPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        clrPanel.add(greenBtn);
        clrPanel.add(redBtn);

        panel.add(clrPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

        cntd = new CountTimer();

    }

    private void setTimerText(String sTime) {
        timeLabel.setText(sTime);
    }


    private void setTimerColor(Color sColor) {
        timeLabel.setForeground(sColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();

        if (btn.equals(greenBtn))        { setTimerColor(Color.GREEN.darker()); } 
        else if (btn.equals(redBtn))     { setTimerColor(Color.RED); }
        else if (btn.equals(startBtn))   { cntd.start(); }
        else if (btn.equals(pauseBtn))   { cntd.pause(); }
        else if (btn.equals(resumeBtn))  { cntd.resume(); }
        else if (btn.equals(stopBtn))    { cntd.stop(); }
        else if (btn.equals(resetBtn))   { cntd.reset(); }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
               new CountTimerGUI();
             }
          });

    }

    private class CountTimer implements ActionListener {

        private static final int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
        private int count = 0;
        private boolean isTimerActive = false;
        private Timer tmr = new Timer(ONE_SECOND, this);

        public CountTimer() {
            count=0;
            setTimerText(TimeFormat(count));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (isTimerActive) {
                count++;
                setTimerText(TimeFormat(count));
            }
        }

        public void start() {
            count = 0; 
            isTimerActive = true;
            tmr.start();
        }

        public void resume() {
            isTimerActive = true;
            tmr.restart();
        }

        public void stop() {
            tmr.stop();
        }

        public void pause() {
            isTimerActive = false;
        }

        public void reset() {
            count = 0;
            isTimerActive = true;
            tmr.restart();

        }

    }

    private String TimeFormat(int count) {

        int hours = count / 3600;
        int minutes = (count-hours*3600)/60;
        int seconds = count-minutes*60;

        return String.format("%02d", hours) + " : " + String.format("%02d", minutes) + " : " + String.format("%02d", seconds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**GUI**:

My preference is to have one `ActionListener` per button. This way you won't have to deal with checking the source before performing an action.

---

Naming the method `GUI()` doesn't follow naming conventions. Methods should start with a lower case letter. `initGUI()` would be a better name as it also describes what is happening in the method.

---

The `CountTimer` is not a GUI component, it should not be in the GUI initialization method.

---

**CountTimer**:

AS you noted, `CountTimer` is tightly coupled with your GUI. This means you will have to do work in order to reuse it in any way. It would be better as a stand-alone class that you just happen to use in a GUI.

I believe the following would be a good interface. It provides that same kind of control and allows the user of the counter to decide what to do when an event occurs.

```
class `CountTimer` {
  CountTimer(TickListener listener);
  void start();
  void stop();
  void pause();
  void resume();
  void reset();
  interface TickListener {
    tick(int count);
  }
}
```

---

You don't set `isTimerActive` to `false` when you stop the timer. In general, this field does not give you anything because stopping the timer will stop events from being fired.

**TimeFormat**:

Again, this function does not follow naming conventions.

---

This should be code that is coupled with the GUI as it deals with the presentation of a number you are tracking, not the actual number value.

---

You can pass multiple arguments to `String.format()`, so you don't need to call it three times. Just create one format sting that accepts all the values you want.

**General**:

Star imports can pollute your namespace and make it hard to track down where a class is coming from.

Comment: A bit confused by the interface you posted. Why did you use `class` (and not `interface`) in the outer one?  Or is it an `abstract class`?

Comment: @PM 77-1 I started out writing a real class, but then decided only the interface was important. So Judy think of it as pseudo-code since you can't specify a constructor in an interface.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to *@unholysampler* and some other notes:

1. I'd avoid abbreviations like `redBtn` and `cntd`. They make the code harder to read and could undermine autocomplete. For example, if you type `redBu` autocomplete won't find anything. It's often annoying. (See also: [nikie's answer on Using single characters for variable names in loops/exceptions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/71723/36726))
2. ```
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ```

   This comment only noise. Remove it. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
3. I think this kind of formatting is really hard to maintain:

   ```
   if (btn.equals(greenBtn))        { setTimerColor(Color.GREEN.darker()); } 
   else if (btn.equals(redBtn))     { setTimerColor(Color.RED); }
   else if (btn.equals(startBtn))   { cntd.start(); }
   else if (btn.equals(pauseBtn))   { cntd.pause(); }
   else if (btn.equals(resumeBtn))  { cntd.resume(); }
   else if (btn.equals(stopBtn))    { cntd.stop(); }
   else if (btn.equals(resetBtn))   { cntd.reset(); }
   ```

   If you have a new variable with a longer name you have to modify seven other lines too to keep it nice. It also looks badly on revison control diff and could cause unnecessary merge conflicts.

   From *Code Complete, 2nd Edition* by *Steve McConnell*, p758:

   > **Do not align right sides of assignment statements**
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > With the benefit of 10 years’ hindsight, I have found that, 
   >   while this indentation style might look attractive, it becomes
   >   a headache to maintain the alignment of the equals signs as variable 
   >   names change and code is run through tools that substitute tabs
   >   for spaces and spaces for tabs. It is also hard to maintain as
   >   lines are moved among different parts of the program that have 
   >   different levels of indentation.

Comment: What do you recommend for `VeryLongNameOfType` variable declaration? `VeryLongNameOfType veryLongNameOfType;`, `VeryLongNameOfType vlnot;`, or something else?

Comment: @PM77-1: I often use `notSoLongNameOfType` or just the last word (or last few words) of the name of the type but I don't think that there is an universal rule here.